# Unable to use the npm run dev

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, backend, web-deployment

used the `npm run dev`

concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"

npm ERR! Missing script: servernpm
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean this?
npm ERR!     npm run server # run the "server" package script

Comment: Please show your package.json file

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to add a script called "dev"

Example:

```json
{
  "name": "My amazing app",
  "version": "x.x.x",
  "main": "foo/fooBar/fooBarz.js",
  "scripts": {
   "dev": "run ./app.js"
   // Other scripts...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    // Stuff..
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    // Stuff..
  },
  "private": true
}
```

And when you run `npm run dev` it will run `run ./app.js` or what ever command you give it, you can also run 2 commands at the same time by using the "&&" operator eg: `command-one start && command-two start`. This operator is just like the "&&" operator in javascript, for more in depth information about this topic why not visit the npmjs doc website I will have a link below to that article post.

LINK: `https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts`

I hope this will help, Like I said if you have any questions just checkout the npm docs.